# Write to textbox.text while running backgroundworker VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code

Hi so i have small form application

the problem was that when i was running tasks on the main thread, the program window wasn't responding

so my button redirects the task to the backgroudworker:

```
Private Sub btn_start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_start.Click

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub
```

Now i want to output to my textbox (txtlog) some text from this Backgroudworker  multiple time in one Sub. I found a solution that allows this. but this makes the code quite ugly if I have to use it several times:

Example

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

        If txtLog.InvokeRequired Then
            txtLog.Invoke(Sub() txtLog.AppendText("My text" & vbNewLine))
            txtLog.Invoke(Sub() txtLog.ScrollToCaret())
        Else
            txtLog.AppendText("My text" & vbNewLine)
            txtLog.ScrollToCaret()
        End If

        Something in Backgroudworker . . .


        If txtLog.InvokeRequired Then
            txtLog.Invoke(Sub() txtLog.AppendText("My text" & vbNewLine))
            txtLog.Invoke(Sub() txtLog.ScrollToCaret())
        Else
            txtLog.AppendText("My text" & vbNewLine)
            txtLog.ScrollToCaret()
        End If
        

       . . . 

End Sub
```

Is there any shorter method that would allow me to write in textbox?

Comment: I always found the ReportProgress event of the background worker a little nicer to deal with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of using a `BackgroundWorker` is so that you don't have to call `Invoke` and use delegates. If you're going to do that anyway then the `BackgroundWorker` is pointless.

With regards to the code you have, what's the point of testing `InvokeRequired` when you know for a fact that the `DoWork` event handler will be executed on a background thread? It's always going to be `True`. Also, why would you call `Invoke` twice and add all that overhead when you can call it once and do as many things as you like in the one call?

```vb
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    txtLog.Invoke(Sub()
                      txtLog.AppendText("My text" & vbNewLine))
                      txtLog.ScrollToCaret()
                  End Sub)
```

As I said though, you shouldn't be calling `Invoke` at all. If you want to do something on the UI thread from a `BackgroundWorker` then you call `ReportProgress` and handle the `ProgressChanged` event. The code you want executed goes in the event handler and you call `ReportProgress` as required. If you need to pass data, you do so using the second argument to `ReportProgress` and get it back from `e.UserState` in the event handler. Here's one I prepared earlier:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Raise the DoWork event in a worker thread.
    Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
 
'This method is executed in a worker thread.
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                     ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
 
    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        'Raise the ProgressChanged event in the UI thread.
        worker.ReportProgress(i, i & " iterations complete")
 
        'Perform some time-consuming operation here.
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
    Next i
End Sub
 
'This method is executed in the UI thread.
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                              ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Me.Label1.Text = TryCast(e.UserState, String)
End Sub
 
'This method is executed in the UI thread.
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                                 ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Me.Label1.Text = "Operation complete"
End Sub
```